# How do I set the compression parameter for PNGs in imsave() (Agg backend)?

Tags: python, matplotlib, compression, png, backend

I want to disable (or lower as much as possible) the compression for `plt.imsave()`. I just want to quickly dump out PNG images that are reused almost instantly anyway.

Any ideas how to do that?

(I am using the agg backend)

Answer (score 2):

From the looks of it, [matplotlib's `pyplot.imsave()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imsave) doesn't support compression options. You should probably use the Python Imaging Library, [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/).

Here's a minimal example of how to save a numpy array as a PNG using [`Image.save()`](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm):

```
import numpy as np, Image as im

img = im.fromarray(np.random.rand(640,480), mode='I')
img.save('test.png', format='PNG', bits=8)
```

The [PNG writer's options](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/format-png.htm) are poorly documented, but the fact that it lets you modify the ZLIB encoder dictionary, among other things, looks promising.

Comment: not really, sorry. I ended up saving the images as tiff with `tifffile`. Thats the fastest way so far.

Comment: @P.R.: At least you found a replacement to `plt.imsave()`. I'm not a fan of PIL myself, but it sometimes has some key image processing functionality I can't seem to find elsewhere.